# Email messages: header section of an email-message, email-message envelope, email-message body and SMTP

Tags: email, smtp

Please, let me know whether my understanding of these things is correct:

- Email-message consits of two parts: email-message envelope and contents of an email-message.
- Email-message envelope is an information that is formed step by step during
  SMTP-handhaking phases on a path of a message from sender's mailbox
  to reciever's mailbox (during exchanging command-reply pairs between each
  SMTP-client and SMTP-server on a path).
- Header section is one of the two parts of a content of an email-message
  (along with message body), and initially consists of the lines written by sender along with the body of the message in his email client.
- Body of the email message - this thing is self-explanatory.
- RFC 5322 specifies the format of the email-message content (header section and message body), and RFC 5321 specifies the work of the SMTP protocol.
- Although header section of the email-message is initially formed by sender of email-message along with the body of the message (in his email-client), this header section may be further extended with some header fields containing envelope information during the path of the email-message through different SMTP-servers. For example, SMTP-server can append a new "Received:" header line to the header section. These modifications of header section must be performed according to the rules from RFC 5321 and after each of these modifications the resulting header section must me consistent with the format specified in RFC 5322.
- When we open a received email-message with an email-client GUI, we see only the message body and a part of the header section of the message that was initially written by sender of email-message in his email client. But if we want to look at the full header section of the message (with those header lines containing envelope information, that were appended by SMTP servers) we can use options like "show original" in Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody answered, I will do it - I have spent some days looking for information about it, have read in RFC 5321 and RFC 5322 the most important moments and hasn't found any contradictions to the assumptions in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This article will explain everything about email header and email envelope: [**What is email envelope and email header**](https://www.mybluelinux.com/what-is-email-envelope-and-email-header/)

- Email-message consits of two parts: email-message envelope and contents of an email-message. >>**YES**
- Email-message envelope is an information that is formed step by step during SMTP-handhaking phases on a path of a message from sender's mailbox to reciever's mailbox (during exchanging command-reply pairs between each SMTP-client and SMTP-server on a path). >>**YES**
- Header section is one of the two parts of a content of an email-message (along with message body), and initially consists of the lines written by sender along with the body of the message in his email client. >>**YES**
- Body of the email message - this thing is self-explanatory.
- RFC 5322 specifies the format of the email-message content (header section and message body), and RFC 5321 specifies the work of the SMTP protocol. **YES**
- Although header section of the email-message is initially formed by sender of email-message along with the body of the message (in his email-client), this header section may be further extended with some header fields containing envelope information during the path of the email-message through different SMTP-servers. For example, SMTP-server can append a new "Received:" header line to the header section. These modifications of header section must be performed according to the rules from RFC 5321 and after each of these modifications the resulting header section must me consistent with the format specified in RFC 5322. >>**YES**
- When we open a received email-message with an email-client GUI, we see only the message body and a part of the header section of the message that was initially written by sender of email-message in his email client. But if we want to look at the full header section of the message (with those header lines containing envelope information, that were appended by SMTP servers) we can use options like "show original" in Gmail. >>**It depend on email cliet, but it is right in general**